# Datepicker: pressing esc retains placeholder text as value

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a simple datepicker I'm using on a couple of date inputs.  Here's the code:

```
$('input.isDate').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('placeholder'); //default is to keep placeholder style format
    },                                      
    onClose: function () {
        $(this).focus(); //otherwise focus goes to neverneverland
    }
});
```

Datepicker shows on focus.  The two .isDate inputs have a placeholder value of "Date".

The problem arises if the user presses the escape key when in the datepicker.  The intended behavior of this is to close the datepicker and restore whatever text was in the box at point of entry. In my case the input box's value becomes the placeholder value.  Leaving the box at this point leaves the word "Date" in the box as a hard value rather than as a placeholder prompt, so it trips some field-level date validation that I have.

I've been able to deal with that by blanking the text value when the user leaves the box, but the user oughtn't to have to erase that text when he escapes out of the datepicker to enter a date manually.  I've made numerous attempts to use events to get rid of this, and none of them work: I've tried focusin, trapping esc in keypress, and the create, beforeDisplay, onSelect and onClose events of the datepicker itself.  In all these cases, the value of the box was still "".  Clearly, the datepicker sets the value of the box after finishing all of its business, and I'm thinking that placeholder wasn't taken into account in this design.  Possibly a bug?  We're using the Whitelabel skin, so maybe they are interfering with the datepicker in some way?  Anyway, I'd much appreciate a workaround or an explanation.  I haven't been able to find much of either.

TIA

Comment: How are you providing the placholder value?  Are you actually using the `placeholder` attribute?  Perhaps it would be helpful to post your HTML -- better yet, put a test case on jsFiddle.

Comment: Yes, using the placeholder attribute.  HTML is pretty straightforward: `<input id="endTime" placeholder="Time" name="End Time">`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your application, I think you'd be better off using a good label and leaving the input blank.  There is also an actual placeholder feature in "HTML5".

Comment: I could do that.  I'm still rather inexperienced at web development, and it's pretty clear that there is plenty of functionality out there that is to be avoided.  Internet Explorer, for example.  :)  But I'd like to get to the bottom of this if I can.

Comment: When I said that, I thought you were setting `value=""` to provide a placeholder. I was recommending using a label instead of that. It's certainly legit to do it with `placholder=""`, but I don't know how good the support is. I'm curious what is happening here too.  I get the gist of it, but I am having a bit of trouble following the narrative -- e.g. I'm not sure what "In my case the input box's value becomes the placeholder value." means. Would be helpful if you could post a demo, especially on jsFiddle, w/ really clear steps to reproduce. What UAs does / doesn't this happen in?